# How to find first array element with value greater than X in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with numeric values and I want to get key of first element which has value equal or greater than 5. Is there more elegant way than looping all elements in `foreach`?

```
// "dirty" way
foreach ([0, 0, 4, 4, 5, 7] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value >= 5) {
        echo $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why its the dirty way?

Comment: This looks fine to me... Perhaps it would be "cleaner" to use `array_walk`/`array_map` and place the test in a separate function...

Comment: Well, is the array always sorted?

Comment: By elegant I mean if there exist built-in PHP function which can deal with it with less effort... This solution works, I just preffer best solutions instead of good one (in case this is not the best).

Comment: @Jack Yes, values are always in this order.

Comment: Just write your own function, in case you need to reuse it. You cannot make it much simpler than that ^^

Comment: On big sorted arrays you may get better performance using binary search; that would be more code though and not necessarily more elegant either.

Comment: What you show is in fact the most optimal solution. There will have to be a loop of some sort inspecting every element in turn. Your solution breaks as soon as it finds that sought element, which means it's the most minimalist solution available.

Comment: You wrote the best approach already. Case closed.

Comment: If the array the array is sorted (it seems it is in the example) you could use a quicksort style approach - checking the middle value and discarding half in each iteration...more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

The algorithm itself is perfectly fine, don't touch it.

That said, you could add some ribbons by writing a generic search function:

```
// find first key (from beginning of $a) for which the corresponding
// array element satisfies predicate $fn
function array_find(array $a, callable $fn)
{
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        if ($fn($value, $key, $a)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$key = array_find([0, 0, 4, 4, 5, 7], function($value) {
    return $value >= 5;
});
```

Now, although this is a more elegant approach, it's less efficient; there's a considerable overhead of calling the closure at each item. If performance is paramount, use what you have and run with it.

Answer (score -1):

Using `array_search()` can be efficient when seeking the earliest occurring match, but it is inappropriate in this case because it will not allow you to supply your required logic to the search.

Using functional iterators like `array_map()` and `array_filter()` are not ideal because they lack the ability to "short circuit" as soon as a match is made.  In my own professional projects, I would not use a functional-style technique -- even on a relatively small data set -- because there is no valuable gain in doing so.

Considering the above, just use a classic loop with a condition in its body which breaks the loop as soon as a qualifying match occurs.

The `$test` variable is defined within a loop of test cases in my runnable demo links.  To trial my code below, be sure to define `$test` as your needle before entering the loop.

**Earliest key where array value is greater than or equal to the needle**: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QM8rK))

```
$array = [0, 0, 4, 4, 5, 7];

$foundKey = 'not found';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value >= $test) {
        $foundKey = $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Get key of highest value not greater than the needle**: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oONnG))

```
$array = [0, 0, 4, 4, 5, 7];

$foundKey = 'not found';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value > $test) {
        break;
    }
    $foundKey = $key;
}
```